# How to modify framework's default Web API routes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

It seems there is a built-in default logic for Web API to use the HTTP Verb as the action name if no action was supplied in the URL. For example, I have this route:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiController",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
        );
```

And here are my actions:

```
    public IEnumerable<Conference> Get()
    {
        ...
    }

    [ActionName("current")]
    public IEnumerable<Conference> GetCurrent()
    {
        ...
    }
```

When I go to **~/Conferences** with a GET verb, it will take you to the "Get()" action. If using the POST verb, it will take you to the "Post([FromBody]Conference value)" action... and so forth. There is a conflict though when you try to go to ~/Conferences/GetCurrent (even though I have [ActionName("current")] on top):

> Multiple actions were found that match the request:
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyApp.Models.Conference]
>   Get() on type MyApp.Api.ConferencesController
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyApp.Models.Conference]
>   GetCurrent() on type MyApp.Api.ConferencesController

This implies the framework is using StartsWith instead of Equal to determine a default action. Also it is ignoring the ActionName attribute when matching verb to action.

My question is how do I make the framework's default action to match to the verb exactly, instead of using StartsWith logic? A GET verb should match only a Get() action, not Get(), GetCurrent() GetPast(), etc (especially when it is ignoring the ActionName attribute).

**EDIT**
For simplicity, I only showed one of my routes above. I think it may help if I show all my routes which is still in draft. I am trying to get a fully working REST API while still leaving room for adding my own custom actions:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiControllerActionId",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: null,
            constraints: new { action = @"^[a-zA-Z]+$", id = @"^\d+$" } // action must start with character
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiControllerActionName",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{name}",
            defaults: null,
            constraints: new { action = @"^[a-zA-Z]+$", name = @"^[a-zA-Z]+$" } // action and name must start with character
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiControllerId",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: null,
            constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } // id must be all digits
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiControllerAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: null,
            constraints: new { action = @"^[a-zA-Z]+$" } // action must start with character
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiController",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
        );
```

**UPDATE**
It seems that adding HTTP verb contraints helped:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiControllerGet",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
            defaults: new { action = "Get" },
            constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiControllerPost",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
            defaults: new { action = "Post" },
            constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiControllerPut",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
            defaults: new { action = "Put" },
            constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Put) }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiControllerDelete",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
            defaults: new { action = "Delete" },
            constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Delete) }
        );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:** Since you made a big edit to the question, I need to change the response:

In short - this will never work out of the box with Web API, because it will by default dispatch the action:

1. based on action name if {action} is part of the route data
2. based on HTTP verb

However, these two approaches **cannot be mixed in a single controller**, so you will not be able to dispatch actions using both approaches from a single controller (which is what you are trying to do).

You have three ways to fix this:

1. rework your resources, so that you have separate ones for action-name dispatching and verb-based disptaching (which is far from ideal)
2. register routes manually for every of the nested routes. This way you keep dispatching by HTTP verb, but routing clearly points to a specific action. You could use something like `AttributeRouting` (https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting) to simplify this. The downside is obviously you end up with - effectively - one route per action
3. Implement a new `IActionSelector` which would allow you to mix both Verb based and action-name based dispatching in a single controller. This is the most "low-level" solution, but seems exactly like something you want to do. I posted a walkthrough last week - http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/magical-web-api-action-selector-http-verb-and-action-name-dispatching-in-a-single-controller/

Comment: For a REST API, I would still need to get ~/Conferences still working though

Comment: edit: ok now that you posted all your routes, the picture is much clearer ;)

Comment: Awesome article, thx! Also AttributeRouting sounds promising but seems like the Web API performance and caching features are not leveraged.